# Objetos clonados não são iguais ao comparar com o método Object.equals()?

Tags: java, clone

Estava fazendo uns testes de igualdade, e ao comparar dois objetos, sendo um clone do outro, notei que o `equals` retorna `false`, mesmo os objetos sendo idênticos. O retorno não deveriam ser `true` já que são objetos clonados? Por que isso acontece?

Classe do Objeto:

```
public class SomeObject  implements Cloneable{

    private int identifier;
    private String someDescription;

    public SomeObject() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.clone();
    }

    public SomeObject(int identifier, String someDescription) {
        super();
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.someDescription = someDescription;
    }

    public int getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(int identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public String getSomeDescription() {
        return someDescription;
    }

    public void setSomeDescription(String someDescription) {
        this.someDescription = someDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + this.identifier + " - " + this.someDescription + "]";
    }
}
```

O teste que fiz foi:

```
SomeObject obj1 = new SomeObject(1, "Lorem ipsum");
SomeObject obj2 = (SomeObject) obj1.clone();

System.out.println("Object 1: " + obj1);
System.out.println("Object 2: " + obj2);

System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2));
```

Resulta em

> ```
> Object 1: [1 - Lorem ipsum]
> Object 2: [1 - Lorem ipsum]
> São iguais? false
> ```

Teste reproduzido no [ideone](https://ideone.com/80qRml).

Comment: Ótima pergunta eu também tinha esta dúvida ;D

Comment: O seu método `clone()` nunca vai lançar `CloneNotSupportedException` porque o `clone()` do `Object` só o lança se `!(this instanceof Cloneable)`. Assim sendo, você pode colocar um `try-catch` ao redor do `super.clone()`, capturar o `CloneNotSupportedException` e ignorá-la ou então o encapsular em um `AssertionError`. Com isso você se livra de ter o `throws CloneNotSupportedException` no seu método e evita de fazer os demais métodos terem que capturar essa exceção.

Comment: Mais um downvote ingrato, sério as pessoas andam a votar muito por empatia e antipatia ao invés de votar pela qualidade da postagem, os votos estão parecendo like do facebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Objetos clonados não iguais para o método Object.equals()?

Não, certamente não. Ao menos para a implementação padrão do `equals`.

Segundo a documentação do Java:

> *The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).*

**Tradução** (por Google Translate)

> O método `equals` para a classe `Object` implementa a relação de equivalência mais discriminante possível em objetos, ou seja, para quaisquer valores de referência não nulos `x` e `y`, este método retorna `true` se e somente se `x` e `y` se referirem ao mesmo objeto (`x == y` tem o valor `true`).

Ou seja, o comportamento padrão do método `equals` é verificar se os dois objetos apontam para a mesma referência. E quando um objeto é clonado é **criado um novo objeto** com os mesmos valores do objeto antigo.

Então, supondo que o método `equals` não tenha sido sobrescrito, este é exatamente o comportamento esperado.

```
SomeObject obj1 = new SomeObject(1, "Lorem ipsum"); 
SomeObject obj2 = (SomeObject) obj1.clone();

System.out.println(obj1 == obj2);      //false
System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2)); //false
```

Comment: Então dá no mesmo clonar o objeto como eu fiz ou simplesmente fazer `SomeObject obj2 = new SomeObject(1, "Lorem ipsum"); `, caso do exemplo apresentado?

Comment: Isso. Exato. Essa é a intenção.